# change gmt of text file in one line with awk and date

Tags: date, awk

I have a file with some fields like these:

```
OID   ,"DATA","PARENT ","APP       ","DSN     ","JOB            ",RUN_,START ,END   ,NDICATOR,"SUB ",FROM_TIME   ,TO_TIME     ,TYPE ,TASK,CRIT,"NOD ","OWNER   ","AUTH ","CMD  ","DESC        ",CONF,CYCL,TYPE,IND_CYCLIC,INT,MAX_
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",1 ,18:30:00 GMT+00:00,18:30:50 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,        
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",2 ,19:00:10 GMT+00:00,19:01:00 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,        
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",3 ,19:30:20 GMT+00:00,19:31:10 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,        
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",4 ,20:00:30 GMT+00:00,20:01:20 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points ",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M, 
.....
```

I only can get from time and add 1 hour,for these I use awk and store in a variable and then I use date to add 1 hour

```
echo $(date -d "$variable 1hour" +%H:%M:%S)
```

The desired output is add one hour to START header:

```
19:30:00
20:00:10
20:30:20
21:00:30
```

Is possible to get that with only one command?

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Hi, the output desired is the from_time hours +1 hour: 19:30:00
20:00:10
20:30:20
21:00:30

Comment: I've edit main post

Comment: Do you need to take daylight savings time and leap seconds into account (i.e. operate using real-world dates/times) or do you just need to add 1 to each hour, wrapping at 24? Also - do you have GNU awk available (try `awk --version`).

Comment: I need add 1 to each hour of the field From_time. I put the output desired in main post

Comment: You mean "add 1 hours to the START column", right? The FROM_TIME column has value "19:30" for every row.

Comment: @glennjackman is correct, your stated requirements don't match your data. Fix your question to state exactly which column it is you need to work on and show the expected output after transforming that column.

Comment: Sorry the column is start, not from time.Start have: 18:30:00 GMT+00:00, 19:00:10 GMT+00:00,19:30:20 GMT+00:00, and 20:00:30 GMT+00:00

Answer (score 0):

I would use a proper CSV parser on that file -- I would want to allow quoted fields to contain commas.

Here's some python that does the CSV parsing and the date arithmetic:

```
python3 <<'END'
import csv, datetime, re
hour = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
file = "file.csv"
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.__next__()
    for row in reader: 
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub(r':(\d\d)$', r'\1', row[7]), '%H:%M:%S %Z%z')
        print((t + hour).strftime("%T"))
END
```

```
19:30:00
20:00:10
20:30:20
21:00:30
```

(Caveat, I don't use python day-to-day so this may not be idiomatic python)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT and gensub():

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=',' '
    { $8=sprintf("%02d%s",($8+1)%24,gensub(/[^:]+/,"",1,$8)); print }
' file
OID   ,"DATA","PARENT ","APP       ","DSN     ","JOB            ",RUN_,01,END   ,NDICATOR,"SUB ",FROM_TIME   ,TO_TIME     ,TYPE ,TASK,CRIT,"NOD ","OWNER   ","AUTH ","CMD  ","DESC        ",CONF,CYCL,TYPE,IND_CYCLIC,INT,MAX_
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",1 ,19:30:00 GMT+00:00,18:30:50 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",2 ,20:00:10 GMT+00:00,19:01:00 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",3 ,20:30:20 GMT+00:00,19:31:10 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points CHANGE232",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,
14082 ,"CEX         ","HOME_TABLE          ","ALERT          ","        ","job_ALERT_00002_home",4 ,21:00:30 GMT+00:00,20:01:20 GMT+00:00, ,"home          ",19:30       ,18:55       ,OS        ,Job       ,0    ,"home  ","system","user1 ","hostname       ","Update points ",0    ,1    ,Interval  ,S       ,00030M,
```

With the above quoted fields can contain commas.

Comment: Wooo! and If I would like to modify next field (END), should I add other -v modifier in awk? I'm trying to decode your code. Thanks!

Comment: No. Look up [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content) and [OFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators) in the GNU awk manual to see what they do. Notice the `$8` in the script? That represents the 8th field, the START one, - repeat what I'm doing for that field to any other field to make the same change to it.